# Cannot convert of type class java.sql.Timestamp to class org.joda.time.DateTime

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, jodatime, formatdatetime

Using `jdk-1.7.0_51` and `tomcat-7.0.42` on `windows 7` platform my JSP page at:

```
<fmt:formatDate value='${abtest.modifiedDate}' pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"/>
```

where the `abtest.modifiedDate` attribute is of type `java.util.Date` and initialized with `java.sql.Timestamp` instance.

throws the following exception:

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert 1/24/14 4:31 PM of type class java.sql.Timestamp to class org.joda.time.DateTime
```

The error seems to be strange because `abtest.modifiedDate` attribute is not initialized with `org.joda.time.DateTime` and it doesn't occur in all environments.

Have also tried to replace: `<fmt:formatDate...` with `<joda:format ...` tag but got another error:

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: value attribute of format tag must be a ReadableInstant or ReadablePartial, was: java.sql.Timestamp
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this annotation on your `DateTime` field in your entity class

```
@Type(type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime birthDay;
```

And in your `JSP`, keep using the `joda format tag`:

```
<c:set var="formattedDateTimeValue">
  <joda:format value="${DateTimeValue}" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" />
  <!-- Or any pattern you want -->
</c:set>
```